# select query with empty "where". octobercms

Tags: php, mysql, octobercms

I use code for filtering via $_GET

```
    $this['painting'] = Painting::
    where('p_price',$p_price)->
    where('p_created',$p_created)   ->
    where('type_id',$type_id)   ->
    whereHas('artist', function($q)
        {
             $q->where('artist_slug', '=', $this->param('slug'));
        })->get();
```

url is `mysite/page.php?type_id=3&p_created=1996` All ok.

But if I have empty some parameter I have no result. For example url is `mysite/page.php?type_id=&p_created=1996` or url is `mysite/page.php?type_id=3&p_created=`return empty string

Now i use something like it

```
if (!$p_created and !$type_id){
    $this['painting'] = Painting::
    whereHas('artist', function($q)
        {
             $q->where('artist_slug', '=', $this->param('slug'));
        })->get();
}
elseif (!$p_created and $type_id){
        $this['painting'] = Painting::
        where('type_id',$type_id)   ->
        whereHas('artist', function($q)
        {
             $q->where('artist_slug', '=', $this->param('slug'));
        })->get();
}
elseif ($p_created and !$type_id){
        $this['painting'] = Painting::
        where('p_created',$p_created)   ->
        whereHas('artist', function($q)
        {
             $q->where('artist_slug', '=', $this->param('slug'));
        })->get();
}
    elseif ($p_created and $type_id){
        $this['painting'] = Painting::
    where('p_created',$p_created)   ->
    where('type_id',$type_id)   ->
    whereHas('artist', function($q)
        {
             $q->where('artist_slug', '=', $this->param('slug'));
        })->get();

}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know OctoberCMS, and I don't see an obvious way to get a basic query object to work with, but you could simulate that by doing a query which will always return true. Something like this:

```
// Assuming type_id is always a positive integer, no nulls allowed
$this['painting'] = Painting::where('type_id', '>', -1);
```

Then you add each condition, if it exists:

```
if ($this->param('slug')){
    $this['painting'] = $this['painting']->
        whereHas('artist', function($q){
             $q->where('artist_slug', '=', $this->param('slug'));
        });
}
if ($p_created){
    $this['painting'] = $this['painting']->
        where('p_created',$p_created);
}
if ($type_id){
    $this['painting'] = $this['painting']->
        where('type_id',$type_id);
}
```

Finally, get the results:

```
$this['painting'] = $this['painting']->get();
```

You many not need to always do `$this['painting'] = $this['painting']->where`, simply `$this['painting']->where` may suffice, depending on how that object works internally.